# How do I control the table font size in different modes in Ninja Tables?

Tags: css, mobile, font-size, ninja

I have tables that in mobile mode need to be a different font size in mobile mode.

At the moment I have to have a duplicate table with different font size to make this work.

Is there a way of setting this in the CSS so that it is one size in desktop and tablet mode, but a different size in mobile mode?

Any help would be much appreciated!